# Maclaurin series approximate problem

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation, euler-maclaurin

Use the Maclaurin series to find an approximate value for the following
integral:

$$\int_{1}^{12} \sin(x^{4})dx$$

Need help with this question please

Comment: First, you should know the Maclaurin series of $\sin{x}$.  Plug in $x^4$ for $x$ in the series then take the first few terms to have a good estimate of $\sin{x^4}$.  Then integrate each term from 1 to 12.

Comment: @Ty. How "few" terms do you need to have a good estimate over a range from $0$ to $12^4=20736$?! And if you take into account the absolute magnitude of those terms, and cancelling... whoever gave that problem to the OP must be mad as a hatter.

Comment: From some months later, was this a task about the Taylor-MacLaurin series or about the Euler-Maclaurin formula, that is, approximating the integral via composite trapezoidal or midpoint rules and getting control about the remainder terms, and thus compensating and reducing the error, via the formula and derivative of the integrand?